# How to find the values and the corresponding column of those values in a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, vector, statistics, combinations

So on a small scale, let's say I have 5 patients which are the rows of a matrix. In the columns, I have some information like age, sex etc. But the question is on some medications. so let's say I have 4 categorical medications. 1 means the patients received them and 0 otherwise. now for some patients I have this vector (1,1,?,?) meaning that the first two values SHOULD be 1 and I know them, but I don't know what are the "?" for each patient.

I assume it should be a matrix of 5 rows and at least 4 columns. now, how can I find the values of "?" for each row? Also, it is SO important to know that this value belongs to which treatment. (I'm not sure if this part of the question makes sense but I also want to know whether for example (1,1,0,1) was the most repeated combination or (1,1,0,0) was or ( 1,1,1,0) or...

I have almost zero knowledge on stat or math but here is the situation and I would appreciate if someone can explain how I can do it in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this, where `n` is the number of observations that have each pattern:

```r
library(dplyr)
dat <- data.frame(patient = LETTERS[1:20], 
                d1 = 1, 
                d2 = 1, 
                d3 = sample(c(0,1), 20, replace=TRUE), 
                d4 = sample(c(0,1), 20, replace=TRUE))

dat %>% 
  group_by(d1, d2, d3, d4) %>% 
  tally()
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#> # Groups:   d1, d2, d3 [2]
#>      d1    d2    d3    d4     n
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#> 1     1     1     0     0     1
#> 2     1     1     0     1     6
#> 3     1     1     1     0     9
#> 4     1     1     1     1     4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Dave. But no, I mean yes it is a very helpful code but this doesn't answer the question. Let me open up the situation: I have 4 treatments. I know that patients SHOULD take 2 of them, lets say d1 and d2. So I create a binary variable (for example k) taking 1 if patients receive d1 and d2. now K can be 1 for only 2 rows. But I don't know the value for d3 and d4 for the patients. How can I find those values where k=1. And how can I know that those values belonged to which treatment; d3 or d4? And now that I know, which one repeated the most (which I think is then the code you wrote)

Comment: @Aura Apologies for not answering the question, but I guess I'm not seeing what you would want otherwise.  This says that everyone has taken `d1` and `d2` and that of all those people, 1 person took neither `d3` or `d4`, 6 people took `d4` and not `d3`, 9 people took `d3` and not `d4` and four people took `d3` and `d4` - all in addition to `d1` and `d2`.  If the values of `d3` and `d4` are truly unknown (i.e., not in your data), then that's a different problem that we can't solve in R.

Comment: Many thanks )... But assume a dataset of 12000 rows. while the number of treatments is 30. so I would have to go through all the 12000 rows and follow 30 columns to find out what n is, or not? Because this is my understanding from your example. The values are known of course! It is just that I dont know that for those rows that d1 and d2 is 1, whether patients took d3 or d4 or both or...

Comment: But I am going to now run the code to see what I get :) I will update here and confirm the answer if it works :) Many thanks Dave!